# Would a method call be considered an expression in Java?

Tags: java, expression

If I had a method call in Java would that not be considered an expression?

In the Java docs though they do not bold the method calls themselves such as System.out.println() method call. Why is that? I thought it would be considered an expressions since the method call returns a value.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/expressions.html

Comment: All method calls, function calls, procedure calls, whatever they are referred to as in *any* language, is an "expression" or part of one. .... Because they return a value or "void" to be used in an expression or assignment, which is an expression. (But technically you will get a syntax error if a "method" returns void in some languages.)

Comment: Method invocations _are_ expressions. it's just a tutorial, not the language specification. Plus, it doesn't say anything about what the non-bolded parts are, so it's still technically correct.

Comment: Upon further inspection, the tutorial is technically wrong. The `cadence = 0` part in `int cadence = 0;` is not an expression, it is syntactically part of a variable declarator list. But do keep in mind that this is a _tutorial_, and sometimes it simplifies things so as not to confuse you. If you want the full picture, go read the language specification.

Comment: @Sweeper the `0` part is an expression, technically.